# Page Object Model- Common element across few pages

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

(Page Object Model- Common element across few pages)

I have a footer element with many child elements. These are common across 4 pages.
I could define the same element across all the pages, but I would rather like to define a common element, accessible by all the pages. I already have a base page class which all my pages are inherited from. But I don't want to fill my base class with common UI elements (as I will end up having many elements). Is there a strategy that you use for these kinds of elements?

```
        bool value = loginPage.FooterIndicator.ElementAt(1).GetAttribute("class").Contains("active");
        bool value = adminPage.FooterIndicator.ElementAt(1).GetAttribute("class").Contains("active");
        bool value = userPage.FooterIndicator.ElementAt(1).GetAttribute("class").Contains("active");
        bool value = samplePage.FooterIndicator.ElementAt(1).GetAttribute("class").Contains("active");
```

In the page -

```
  public IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FooterIndicator=> driver.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
```

Thanks

Comment: [component object pattern](https://lkrnac.net/blog/2016/10/component-object-pattern-example/) would be one way of addressing your concern. or a [wrapper](https://medium.com/@boriscoder/page-object-for-testing-react-js-components-49cddb59adb7)

Comment: Can you provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added the code example above

Comment: Create a class which has these footer elements and extend from the base page. Extend the new class for the pages which require these footer elements. For the rest extend the base class.